# EDSDK callbacks not working after NSPrintPanel/NSPrintOperation Displayed

Tags: objective-c, macos, callback, edsdk, nsprintoperation

I am currently developing an application using the Canon EDSDK to access my DSLR that will directly print the shot images. The problem here is, that my code interfacing with the EDSDK works perfectly until my application displays either a NSPrintPanel or NSPrintOperation.
If one of these is displayed using either the "runModalX" or "beginSheetWith" functions, and quit again (either Cancel or Ok does not seem to make a difference), then the callbacks within EDSDK seem to stop working.
I can still interface with the camera, download live view images, shoot images, but no action relying on a callback works anymore. An example code, how I call my NSPrintPanel is here:

```
NSPrintInfo * printInfo = [NSPrintInfo sharedPrintInfo];
NSPrintPanel * printPanel = [NSPrintPanel printPanel];
NSInteger result = [printPanel runModalWithPrintInfo: printInfo];
```

This is how I invoke the NSPrintOperation:

```
//view is a NSView with some data added, info is obtained as above
NSPrintOperation * printOp = [NSPrintOperation printOperationWithView: view printInfo: printInfo];
[printOp setShowsPrintPanel: NO];
[printOp runOperation];
```

My thought is that somehow displaying this panel messes with the messages sent around in the current application. The Cocoa application templates generated by Xcode already provide the print functionality to my Application via the "File->Print" Menu. If the print window is displayed this way, it causes the same errors, only if I display a print dialog outside my application (eg. from Safari) while my application runs, then it does not mess up the EDSDK.

Does anybody have an idea, what the problem here could be, or even how to solve it?

On a side-note: if I take Canons sample application "Camera Control" and add the above code, it ends up having the same problem: live view still works, any interaction with the camera works, but callbacks are not called (so sending the "take picture" command even works the shutter, but since the camera is waiting for the computer to download the shot image, no shutter release after that works).